# Transition on Layout change

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

## Layout Change Transition

I have a parent container with two child elements inside it: child1 and child2. The parent container has its display property set to 'flex' with a 'row' direction, but for screens larger than 768px, I want it to change to 'flex-col' direction. How can I add a smooth transition to this layout change, so when the screen size increases from 768px or higher and the flex direction changes, it transitions smoothly instead of abruptly?

```
<style>
    .parent {
        display: flex;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
    .child1, .child2{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .child1{
        background:red;
    }
    .child1{
        background:blue;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .parent {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Layout changes from `flex-direction` are [discrete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#formal_definition). CSS offers no out of the box support for interpolation on that property . There are js-libraries to perform [FLIP](https://css-tricks.com/animating-layouts-with-the-flip-technique/)(first,last,inverse,play) animation. for example: [flipping.js](https://jsfiddle.net/q15fxeyv/1/) or [framer-motion](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-cookies-gzkcgr?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with CSS, because `flex-direction` is not an animatable property.

However, you can do something similar with JavaScript, but I don't know if it fits your needs.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    document.querySelector(".child2").style.translate = "-100px 100px";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".child2").style.translate = "0";
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child1,
.child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```